# How to get the means of all columns but one?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, mean

I have a data like below :

```
> dplyr::tbl_df(sbp)

Country X1980       X1981       X1982       X1983       X1984       X1985
Albania 132.9270    133.0296    133.1459    133.1868    133.2048    133.2577        
Algeria 132.4093    132.1710    131.9649    131.7835    131.6161    131.4345        
Andorra 140.8585    140.1076    139.3727    138.6457    137.9525    137.3192
```

I want to get mean of values for each year for all countries and add a row like World to the end of the dataframe, so that I can plot the change of the mean value through years, in that format.

I tried using `gather()` so that I have a data with three columns only, like Country-year-value. However I can not think of a way to calculate the mean for the world.

```
Country year    sbp
Albania X1980   132.9270        
Algeria X1980   132.4093        
Andorra X1980   140.8585
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: you're looking for something like `sbp$mean = rowMeans(sbp[,-1])`?

Comment: `df %>% select(-1) %>% colMeans()`? Could then `rbind` these to your data with leading value `"World"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case for `apply`, no transformations from your original format necessary:

`1` means to calculate across rows, and we select columns `2:6`

`df1$mean <- apply(df1[,2:6], 1, mean)`

```
  Country    X1980    X1981    X1982    X1983    X1984    X1985     mean
1 Albania 132.9270 133.0296 133.1459 133.1868 133.2048 133.2577 133.0988
2 Algeria 132.4093 132.1710 131.9649 131.7835 131.6161 131.4345 131.9890
3 Andorra 140.8585 140.1076 139.3727 138.6457 137.9525 137.3192 139.3874
```

You don't really want to add a summary row to your primary table, that's how you might do it in Excel, but in R it's better practice to calculate it separately.

To get the means for each year, we can also use apply, this time using `2` in the `apply` function to calculate down columns:

```
apply(df1[,2:6], 2, mean)


   X1980    X1981    X1982    X1983    X1984 
135.3983 135.1027 134.8278 134.5387 134.2578
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with base R:

```
rbind(mydf, cbind(Country = 'World', as.data.frame.list(colMeans(mydf[,-1]))))
```

which gives:

> ```
>   Country    X1980    X1981    X1982    X1983    X1984    X1985
> 1 Albania 132.9270 133.0296 133.1459 133.1868 133.2048 133.2577
> 2 Algeria 132.4093 132.1710 131.9649 131.7835 131.6161 131.4345
> 3 Andorra 140.8585 140.1076 139.3727 138.6457 137.9525 137.3192
> 4   World 135.3983 135.1027 134.8278 134.5387 134.2578 134.0038
> ```

And a `tidyverse` solution:

```
mydf %>% 
  gather(year, sbp, -1) %>% 
  bind_rows(., mydf %>% 
              gather(year, sbp, -1) %>%
              group_by(year) %>%
              summarise(Country = 'World', sbp = mean(sbp)))
```

with a long format outcome:

> ```
>    Country  year      sbp
> 1  Albania X1980 132.9270
> 2  Algeria X1980 132.4093
> 3  Andorra X1980 140.8585
> 4  Albania X1981 133.0296
> 5  Algeria X1981 132.1710
> 6  Andorra X1981 140.1076
> 7  Albania X1982 133.1459
> 8  Algeria X1982 131.9649
> 9  Andorra X1982 139.3727
> 10 Albania X1983 133.1868
> 11 Algeria X1983 131.7835
> 12 Andorra X1983 138.6457
> 13 Albania X1984 133.2048
> 14 Algeria X1984 131.6161
> 15 Andorra X1984 137.9525
> 16 Albania X1985 133.2577
> 17 Algeria X1985 131.4345
> 18 Andorra X1985 137.3192
> 19   World X1980 135.3983
> 20   World X1981 135.1027
> 21   World X1982 134.8278
> 22   World X1983 134.5387
> 23   World X1984 134.2578
> 24   World X1985 134.0038
> ```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text="Country X1980       X1981       X1982       X1983       X1984       X1985
Albania 132.9270    133.0296    133.1459    133.1868    133.2048    133.2577        
Algeria 132.4093    132.1710    131.9649    131.7835    131.6161    131.4345        
Andorra 140.8585    140.1076    139.3727    138.6457    137.9525    137.3192", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the means for each year using

```
world_means <- tbl %>% 
    select(-Country) %>% summarise_all(mean) %>%
    cbind(list(Country="World"), .)
```

It just computes the mean for all columns except `Country` and then binds that with a `Country` we call `"World"`. To add it to your table, simply use `rbind`:

```
rbind(tbl, world_means)
```